# Impossible to overlay gradient over background image?

Tags: css, background, overlay, gradient

I'm finding it impossible to get the background image on my site (www.thegreateverything.com) to fade away completely to white when scrolling down the page. I'm trying to achieve the same effect as the background image on this site: https://www.garyvaynerchuk.com/askgaryvee-episode-173-book-marketing-snapchat-growth-tipping-points-in-history/

I've looked through similar questions from others but none of the answers seem to work. I'm new to coding and using CSS, and the Valenti theme.

If anyone can crack this, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Please include what code you have so far.

Comment: Like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yeXQmd

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hunter - I have no code on this aspect of the site (I've just removed a whole load that didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the effect that you are looking for. The contentHolder article acts as gradient layer so that this can produce the background effect like the website you have given us.

ALSO, the gradient code was taken from Colorzilla gradient generator.
You will probably need this because it might take awhile to edit the gradient to your liking.

```css
body { 
margin: 0px;
background-image: url(https://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
}

#contentHolder {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.43) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.51) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0.74) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,0.81) 59%, rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 82%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.43) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.51) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,0.74) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,0.81) 59%,rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 82%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.43) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.51) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,0.74) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,0.81) 59%,rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 82%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6effffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
margin-top: 500px;
}

#mainContent {
background: blue;
padding-bottom: 2500px;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-right: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
 <article id="contentHolder">
  <section id="mainContent">
   <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
  </section>
 </article>

</body>
```

Comment: Man, I wish this worked! Really appreciate your efforts, but I'll have to keep searching.

Comment: BTW What is exactly wrong with my answer? I'm not trying to complain here but could you possibly tell me what's wrong? I will be able to easily edit my question accordingly

Comment: Do you want me to use jquery for this?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it just didn't bring about any changes at all. But I've tried all kinds of things from other kind and knowledgeable people (across various question boards) and nothing seems to work, so there must be something else going on that I haven't detected yet.

Comment: Could you possibly give me the layout of your site?

Comment: Sure. It's at thegreateverything.com

Comment: So you want the background of the man playing a trumpet to fade out as you scroll down??